# AppleScript: "set frontmost to true" does not work when the screensaver is running?

Tags: applescript

I have a shell script `foo.sh` which would keep running in a Terminal window. When some condition is true `foo.sh` would call an AppleScript `bar.osa` to make Thunderbird go offline. Following is the `bar.osa` script (my first applescript):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Thunderbird"
  set frontmost to true
  tell menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
    tell menu "File"
      tell menu item "Offline"
        tell menu "Offline"
          set v to (value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Work Offline") as string
          if (v is not equal to "✓") then
            click menu item "Work Offline"
          end if
        end tell
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

This works fine for most of the time but when the screensaver is running it does not work. Seems like `set frontmost to true` does not work when the screen is locked. So how can I make it work even when the screensaver is running?

Answer (score 1):

I am on mavericks, and there is no way I can figure out if the screen saver is running, all I can recommend you to do, is to check the status afterwards of the frontmost property of "Thunderbird".

I have actually spent a good hour on this, and I hope that someone else comes up with a solution, that works! :)

**Edit**

Actually it was my bad, I thought that launching the ScreenSaver from the System Preferences Preview pane would do it. 
When I run the screen saver started from a script, then the running property of it works.

```
tell application id "sevs" -- "System Events"
   set itsRunning to false
   if (running of screen saver preferences) then
       set itsRunning to true
   end if
end tell

if itsRunning then
   tell application id "com.apple.ScreenSaver.Engine" to quit
end if
```

So the solution I propose, is to check if frontmost is true after you have set it frontmost, if the screen saver is running, then turn off the screen saver (requires that you have no password on the screen saver, then rerun the code that sets your app frontmost, and then finally launches the screen saver again.

```
 try
     tell application id "com.apple.ScreenSaver.Engine" to launch
 end try
```

You can make this to work in a `repeat` loop, of course you don't have to use a repeat loop.

**Edit+** I was really tired last night: you can really just start out by testing if the screensaver is running, and then either drop going forward, or turn the screen saver off, do your stuff, and turn it on again.

Comment: Thanks. I still need a solution which works for password protected screensaver.

Comment: Hello. There is actually one thing you can do, and that is to write an 'expect script', that sudoes to root, so that you can KillAll ScreenSaverEngine. See **man expect**. When you start the ScreenSaverEngine again, then you do that in some usual way, so that it is started with your password, and not the Admins. This is the only means I can think of. I have no experience with expect, but it is delivered with OS X, and you have to see to that sudo works. ScreenSaverEngine may be a wrong process name as well, use ActivityMonitor or something to figure it out. Good Luck

Comment: Here. [MacScripter / help to make simple shell script or Apple script](http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=138402#p138402) is an example of an expect script, you can look at, while you read about the command.

Comment: One more thing, the way I personally would solve this, should I have a similiar problem of my own, is to check for if the screen saver is frontmost, if it is, then I'd postpone doing anything, until the screen saver gets off. I see that as less complicated problem, and it really doesn't matter to me, what is frontmost at the time when the screen saver is on, anyway. I realize you may have valid reasons for doing so, just mentioning how I would have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I need to make Thunderbird offline as soon as the condition is true no matter if the screensaver is running or not. As a workaround I can simply ask Thunderbird to quit. Though I still want to see if there's a more elegant solution. :) Thanks for all your help.